# Displaying a text file in browser in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I am developing an application in Java Vaadin framework. I have a text (.txt) file which I want to open in web browser. So what can be the ways in Vaadin to display the text file in browser similar to the browser's PDF viewer.
Thanks!

Comment: What about using a TextAreaField?

Comment: Yes I have done it with TextArea. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look at the rich label http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#LabelRich 
You simply use it by doing:

```
Label richText = new Label("yourtext");
richText.setContentMode(Label.CONTENT_XHTML);
```

The key here is the Lable content mode. You can find more of them at https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Label.html if you want other types of layouts

And to get your text file content into the Label you could use any of the strategies shown at [this link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.se/2012/08/convert-inputstream-to-string-java-example-tutorial.html) or just read in the Java API